# Free hand draw with no overlap

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm writing a paint program for canvas that allows for the adjustment of opacity. However, when it comes to free handing with line widths greater than one, line segments converge on one side and diverge on the other. I am able to fill in the edges with circles, but there are still overlapping sections that ruin the consistency of the opaque color. I've just about had it with this issue, I will be eternally grateful for any help.

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj4BA/).

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button onclick="circles='true';">with circles</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mousedown = false;
circles = false;

canvas.onmousedown = function () {
    x0 = event.clientX;
    y0 = event.clientY;
    mouseDown = true;
}

canvas.onmouseup = function () {
    mouseDown = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function () {
    if (mouseDown) {
        x1 = event.clientX;
        y1 = event.clientY;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 20;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)";
        ctx.stroke();

        if (circles) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)";
            ctx.arc(x1, y1, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        }

        x0 = x1;
        y0 = y1;
    }
}
```

css:

```
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: A few pointers: Draw 1 continuous line instead of many line segments. Use context.lineJoin="round" & context.lineCap="round" to make the line more seamless. If your canvas is not at [0,0], adjust for that offset in the event handlers.  Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/uhxJn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

You can use the canvas property `globalCompositeOperation` and set it to `xor` like this:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhL3U/) for a demo.

---

**Old Answer**

Instead of drawing successive segments with `0.5` alpha, you can draw segments of `1` alpha, and apply an opacity to the canvas.

```
// css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

// js
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
```

See this modified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKtFu/).